# Extracting Multiple Blocks of Similar Text

Tags: regex, recursion, block

I am trying to parse a report.  The following is a sample of the text that I need to parse:

```
7605625112 DELIVERED N 1 GORDON CONTRACTORS I SIPLAST INC Freight Priority 2000037933 $216.67 1,131 ROOFING MATERIALS
04/23/2021 02:57 PM K WRISHT N 4 CAPITOL HEIGHTS, MD ARKADELPHIA, AR Prepaid 2000037933 -$124.23 170160-00
04/27/2021 12:41 PM 2 40 20743-3706 71923 $.00 055 $.00
2 WBA HOT $62.00 0
$12.92 $92.44
$167.36
7605625123 DELIVERED N 1 SECHRIST HALL CO SIPLAST INC Freight Priority 2000037919 $476.75 871 PAIL,UN1263,PAINT,3,
04/23/2021 02:57 PM S CHAVEZ N 39 HARLINGEN, TX ARKADELPHIA, AR Prepaid 2000037919 -$378.54
04/27/2021 01:09 PM 2 479 78550 71923 $.00 085 $95.35
2 HRL HOT $62.00 21
$13.55 $98.21
$173.76
```

This comprised of two or more blocks that start with `"[0-9]{10}\sDELIVERED"` and the last currency string prior to the next block.

If I test with `"(?s)([0-9]{10}\sDELIVERED)(.*)(?<=\$167.36\n)"` I successfully get the first Block, but If I use `"(?s)([0-9]{10}\sDELIVERED)(.*)(?<=\$\d\d\d.\d\d\n)"` it grabs everything.

If someone can show me the changes that I need to make to return two or more blocks I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `(?<=` is a positive lookbehind. I can only assume you wanted a positive lookahead `(?=` instead.

Comment: Porbably, all you need is `(?sm)^\d{10}\sDELIVERED.*?(?=\R\d{10}\sDELIVERED|\z)`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MKjOo6/1). Depending on the regex flavor, you will need to adjust the `\z` and `\R` constructs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` is a greedy operator, so it will try to match as much characters as possible. See also [Repetition with Star and Plus](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

For fixing it, you can use this regex:

```
(?s)(\d{10}\sDELIVERED)((.(?!\d{10}\sDELIVERED))*)(?<=\$\d\d\d.\d\d)
```

in which I basically replaced `.*` with `(.(?!\d{10}\sDELIVERED))*` so that for every character it checks if it is followed or not by `\d{10}\sDELIVERED`.

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/4R6Kt0/1)

Comment: `(.(?!\d{10}\sDELIVERED))*` is a corrupt tempered greedy token, it must be written as `(?:(?!\d{10}\sDELIVERED).)*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It depends on what the OP wants to do. I supposed s/he wanted to use the group 0.

Comment: It does not matter what groups are needed and which are not, the problem is with the syntax. TGT is meant to restrict what is to follow, but placing `.` in front skips the first char. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I still don't see the problem. The complexity looks the same to me, in that way you would just save a handful of steps, so I would not use the "must" word.

Comment: You would see a problem if the trailing delimiter occurred right after the leading delimiter. Most probably, this will never happen in 99.9999% of cases. However, the `.` must be placed after the lookahead.

Comment: Thanks to all for your prompt responses.  The pattern noted above (?s)(\d{10}\sDELIVERED)((.(?!\d{10}\sDELIVERED))*)(?<=\$\d\d\d.\d\d) solves my problem.